# Why does variable declared with static, extern and without it contains differenr values

Tags: c++, linkage

Consider the following code snippets:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a=5;

int main ()
{
    extern int a;
    printf("%d\n",a); //5
}

//---------//

#include <stdio.h>

int a=5;

int main ()
{
    static int a;
    printf("%d\n",a); //0
}

//---------//

#include <stdio.h>

int a=5;

int main ()
{
    int a;
    printf("%d\n",a); //12497123435
}
```

I don't understand why 5 displayed when `a` declared with `extern` specifier? When we declare `a` with `static` modifier then `a` has `linkage` and `a` can be denoted an entity from another scope.

Answer (score 6):

When you write `extern int a;`, you're declaring a variable named `a` with extern linkage, but you do not define it. Instead a definition must exist elsewhere - usually in a different translation unit. In this case the definition of `a` is in the same translation unit and the declaration is completely redundant because `a` is already visible. That said a redundant declaration is not an error, so it behaves the same way as if the declaration did not exist at all. If the definition were in a different translation unit, you'd need the declaration, so the compiler knows that the variable exists at all. In either case the extern declaration does not introduce a new variable and `a` simply refers to the global variable.

`static int a` and `int a` however are definitions and introduce a new variable named `a`, so the value of the global variable `a` is no longer relevant.

The difference between `static int a` and `int a` is that they have different storage. `int a` has automatic storage and using an uninitialized variable with automatic storage invokes undefined behavior, which is why you get a "random" value in your case. Variables with static or extern linkage on the other hand are automatically initialized to 0, so that's why you get 0 for your static variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example behaves as expected and is perfectly reasonable. Your second two examples are just bugs. In both of them, you create a new variable called `a` and read its value before setting its value.

Answer (score 0):

`extern int a` is only a *declaration* (i.e an announcement) that a variable with name `a` is *defined* somewhere else, which in your case refers to the global variable.

`static int a` *defines* a variable with static storage duration. Variables of such duration are zero-initialized (statically).

`int a` (in the function scope) *defines* `a` with automatic storage duration. It is uninitialized. Reading its value invoke undefined behavior (UB) — your third example is dangerous, as it invokes UB.